# How to call third party web service using SharePoint designer workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I am trying to connect Sales Force using SharePoint designer workflow(attached to the SharePoint online list).

I am using 'Call http web service' activity to call Sales Force login API with required body content.

I am getting "Bad request" response code.But I am getting success when calling it with Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Does it return in JSON format? If not you need to specify a header to force it to return JSON as workflows only accepts JSON.

Also you might want to look into the error message to give you any hints.

Comment: following is the response {"error_description":"grant type not supported","error":"unsupported_grant_type"}.I was getting same response in postman as well but after adding missing parameter in body it worked well. but not working in designer workflow.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with webservice calls in general, so I'm afraid I wont be of much help here.

Answer (score 0):

Your API is working fine in Postman so, may be an issue is related to workflow configuration in SPD.

In one of my project I had to posted the data from SharePoint to another third Party server.

In my case I had Basic authentication and needed to **POST** JSON data using third party API.

Please correct the settings in SPD workflow as below:

1. If you have Basic authentication in your API then get the all the details from Postman.
   Go to Postman > On right side click on '**Code**' link.
   [image]
2. Next, In SPD we will build our dictionary with below request headers that we will pass for API. Name that dictionary variables as 'reqHeaders'.
   In below image add **application/json;odata=verbose** for **Accept** and **Content-Type**.
   For **Authorization** copy full string from Postman (Image 1) and Paste.
   For **Host** also copy server host name from Postman and paste.
   [image]
3. Next, I had to post JSON data so, I am building another Dictionary with Name **requestBody** to pass the JSON data.

[image]

4. Next, add **Call http web service** action and configure our variables. Right Click on **Call http web service** action and select **Properties** and set our variables in it as below.

[image]

That it!. Your POST call is ready for third party.

For GET method you can change service call accordingly.